# FactoryGirl.create not increasing `.count` field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I had the same problem as Nick Rutten in this thread [Rails Tutorial: RSpec test decoupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606603/rails-tutorial-rspec-test-decoupling). I suspected the problem was the `FactoryGirl.create()` saving to the database, and thanks to @prusswan I fixed it.
However I do not understand why these `puts` don't indicate different `User.count`.

This is the snippet I'm interested in:

```
describe "with valid information" do

  puts "Number of users pre-Factory:" + User.count.to_s
  let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  puts "Number of users post-Factory:" + User.count.to_s

  (...)

end
```

I get:

`Number of users pre-Factory:0`
`Number of users post-Factory:0`

But shouldn't I get instead?:

`Number of users pre-Factory:0`
`Number of users post-Factory:1`

Btw, the factory is defined (although not so relevant now) as:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Example User"
    email "user@example.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

I'm stuck trying to understand why the counter is not increasing, wasn't the problem that it did increase to start with?
thank you

**Edit using @derekyau's suggestions:**

Right now I've got in this order:

```
it "print counter before let"
  puts "Number of users:" + User.count.to_s
end

let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

it "print counter after let"
  puts "Number of users:" + User.count.to_s
end
```

However now I get both values 1:

```
Number of users:1
Number of users:1
```

Close but not there yet!

**Edit 2**

As explained by @Peter Alfvin here: [Within a given RSpec describe block, does the order of let, before and it statements matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037920/within-a-given-rspec-describe-block-does-the-order-of-let-before-and-it-statem) . The order of `let`, `before`, `it` is pretty much established, regardless of the code. That, together with @derekyau's explanation closes the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question, I think that `let(:user)` is lazily evaluated so it isn't actually called until you use it inside of an it block.

If you want to force it to be evaluated try let!

```
let!(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
```

If you want to see it change try doing the puts inside of an "it block"

```
it "check user count" do
  puts User.count
end
```

You should see '1'

Comment: that sounds very reasonable, but it does not work for me! I still get the same number of `User.count` before and after the `let!(:user)`.

Comment: Check my updated answer for this - it seems if you actually want to see whether it has happened, you have to put the "puts" statement inside of an "it block"

Comment: thank you again! Although I am not sure I understand why it reports both counters as `1` now. See post's edit.

Comment: As long as the let!(:user) is in there, the order of how it is included doesn't matter - read this answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037920/within-a-given-rspec-describe-block-does-the-order-of-let-before-and-it-statem

Comment: Now I get it! Too bad there is no way to 'tweak' this for playing-with-it purposes :( That would be great for understanding the underlying functioning. I will try to find @Peter Alfvin's explanation in an official doc. Thank you!